# Woocommerce 'My Account' Not Showing up

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I utilize woocommerce on my custom wordpress theme to sell products. This theme was built by a developer, and I have noticed an issue with customer accounts.

Customers can checkout as a guest, or create an account to manage orders. We have an account page, and the developer included the following shortcode [woocommerce_my_account]. I have checked the woocommerce settings, and they appear to be set properly for my account.

The URL for the page is http://www.domaain.com/my-account/

When a user goes to that page after logging in, it gives the header for the user dashboard, but doesn't populate any of the order history or information.

We want customers to be able to access this, as we are using the 'Subscriptions' plugin now to offer recurring billing options, and we want them to be able to pause, cancel and update payment info.

I have attached a screenshot of what the page looks like when a user is logged in.

Are there any typical issues that may cause this? Are there any trouble shooting suggestions to see how to fix? Thanks for any help

[image: My Account Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved, the issue was overridden php files in the custom theme. They had to be updated from the current woocommerce template

Answer (score 0):

- Rename your woocommerce plugin woocommerce to old-woocommerce
- Download the update one (Woocommerce) and upload the new one VIA file
  manager (cPanel)

Active the new one from your WP-Dashboard

http://user.successfulpeoplestories.com/guest-blog-post/wordpress/how-to-fix-wordpress-blank-page-errors-and-similar-issues/